# Dynamically generated panelGroup can't be located

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the following structure in my application:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Regiões :" />
<p:autoComplete multiple="true" value="#{investimento.regioesSelecionadas}"
                completeMethod="#{investimento.completaRegiao}"
                var="reg" itemLabel="#{reg.label}" itemValue="#{reg}" 
                converter="entityConverter" forceSelection="true">

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{reg.label}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="regiaoCol" />
    <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" update="regiaoCol" />
    <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" listener="#{investimento.tiraUmaRegiao}"/>
</p:autoComplete>

<h:outputText />
<h:panelGroup id="regiaoCol">
    <c:forEach items="#{investimento.regioesSelecionadas}" var="regSel" rendered="#{!investimento.regioesSelecionadas.isEmpty()}">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="Região #{regSel.label} - Estados:" />
            <p:autoComplete multiple="true" value="#{investimento.estadosSelecionados}"
                            var="est" itemLabel="#{est.label}" itemValue="#{est}"
                            completeMethod="#{investimento.completaEstado}" 
                            converter="entityConverter" forceSelection="true" cash="true">
                <f:attribute name="regPar" value="#{regSel}" />
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{est.label}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="#{investimento.idComposta(est, regSel)}" />
                <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" update="regiaoCol" />
                <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" update="#{investimento.idComposta(est, regSel)}"/>
                <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" update="#{investimento.idComposta(est, regSel)}" listener="#{investimento.tiraUmEstado}"/>
            </p:autoComplete>

            <h:outputLabel />
            <h:panelGroup id="#{investimento.idComposta(est, regSel)}">
                <c:forEach items="#{investimento.estadosSelecionados}" var="estSel">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Estado #{estSel.label} - Municipios:               #{investimento.idComposta(est, regSel)}" />
                        <p:autoComplete multiple="true" value="#{investimento.municipiosSelecionados}"
                                        var="mun" itemLabel="#{mun.label}" itemValue="#{mun}"
                                        completeMethod="#{investimento.completaMunicipio}" maxResults="8"
                                        converter="entityConverter" forceSelection="true" cash="true">
                            <f:attribute name="estPar" value="#{estSel}" />
                            <p:column>
                                <h:outputText value="#{mun.label}" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:autoComplete>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </c:forEach>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </c:forEach>
</h:panelGroup>
```

So, whenever I pick a "Região" will apear in "regiaoCol" new options for the user to select. However there's an issue: when I remove a "Região", add it again and try to remove it once more, it causes the following error:

```
> Grave: Error Rendering View[/InsI.xhtml]
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with expression "munEst2Reg3" referenced from "form:j_idt190".
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentInternal(SearchExpressionFacade.java:422)
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentForClient(SearchExpressionFacade.java:200)
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentsForClient(SearchExpressionFacade.java:147)
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addExpressions(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:92)
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.update(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:85)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.getScript(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:80)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorBase.getScript(ClientBehaviorBase.java:103)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.encodeClientBehaviors(CoreRenderer.java:458)
```

Which, I presume, is caused by the browser looking for that reference, in this case "munEst2Reg3" and it not being there. However: why it throws the error? How is it different from removing the "Região" the first time? How to I solve the issue? Should I submit the page after each unselection? (which wouldn't be the most user friendly option)

Comment: There is no component with the `id` `munEst2Reg3` in your current code unless you are setting somewhere dynamically through EL - `id="#{investimento.idComposta(est, regSel)}"`. You are abusing `<c:forEach>`. You can instead use other JSF/PrimeFaces iterating components like `<p:dataTable>`, `<p:dataList>`, `<p:dataGrid>` for the same depending upon your requirements.

Comment: Thanks man! That really illuminated the path!

Answer (score 0):

Tiny's response put me on the right track and, after some debuging I found somethings:

1. As all the instances are altering the same list is paramount that all of them have a  event or one will delete the inputs of the other;
2. You have also to take care on how the dataTable behaves and guarantee that he only gets the values that you are interested in;

How my code ended up being:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Regiões :" />
                <p:autoComplete multiple="true" value="#{investimento.regioesSelecionadas}"
                                completeMethod="#{investimento.completaRegiao}"
                                var="reg" itemLabel="#{reg.label}" itemValue="#{reg}" 
                                converter="entityConverter" forceSelection="true">

                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{reg.label}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="regiaoCol" />
                    <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" update="regiaoCol" listener="#{investimento.tiraUmaRegiao}"/>
                </p:autoComplete>

                <h:outputText />
                <h:panelGroup id="regiaoCol">
                    <p:dataTable value="#{investimento.regioesSelecionadas}" var="regSel" rendered="#{investimento.regioesSelecionadas.isEmpty() == false}">
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputLabel value="Região #{regSel.label} - Estados:" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <p:autoComplete multiple="true" value="#{investimento.estadosSelecionados}"
                                            var="est" itemLabel="#{est.label}" itemValue="#{est}"
                                            completeMethod="#{investimento.completaEstado}" 
                                            converter="entityConverter" forceSelection="true">
                                <f:attribute name="regPar" value="#{regSel}" />

                                <p:column>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{est.label}" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="#{investimento.idComposta()}" >
                                    <f:attribute name="regiaoPar" value="#{regSel}" />
                                </p:ajax>

                                <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" update="#{investimento.idComposta()}" listener="#{investimento.tiraUmEstado}">
                                    <f:attribute name="regiaoPar" value="#{regSel}" />
                                </p:ajax> 
                            </p:autoComplete>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <h:panelGroup id="#{investimento.idComposta()}">
                                <f:attribute name="regiaoPar" value="#{regSel}" />

                                <p:dataTable value="#{investimento.meusEstSel()}" var="estSel" rendered="#{investimento.meusEstSel().isEmpty() == false}">
                                    <f:attribute name="regiaoPar" value="#{regSel}" />
                                    <p:column>
                                        <h:outputLabel value="Estado #{estSel.label} - Municipios:" />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column>
                                        <p:autoComplete multiple="true" value="#{investimento.municipiosSelecionados}"
                                                        var="mun" itemLabel="#{mun.label}" itemValue="#{mun}"
                                                        completeMethod="#{investimento.completaMunicipio}" maxResults="8"
                                                        converter="entityConverter" forceSelection="true">
                                            <f:attribute name="estPar" value="#{estSel}" />

                                            <p:column>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{mun.label}" />
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" />
                                            <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" />
                                        </p:autoComplete>
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:panelGroup>
```